# Disney movie where a professor discovers a new element called "Flubber"

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie 2 years ago. It was a Disney movie where a chemistry professor discovers a new element which he calls flubber. He uses it to design a flying car, an old Model T(?).

The professor had also missed his marriage twice or thrice. If I remember correctly, the movie ends when he lands his car in the lawns of the White House.

The movie was probably a 60s or 70s movie.

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research. Even the most cursory of searches would have led you to the result.

Comment: Is there not even a remake called "Flubber"?

Comment: the movie name is "Flubber"

Comment: @Darren - For the record, the movie "Flubber" isn't actually the movie he's looking for

Comment: @Valorum yes I understand that. But a cursory search of the term would have led the OP down the rabbit hole of remake -> original. In short, it’s a lazy question.

Answer (score 13):

This is [The Absent-Minded Professor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Absent-Minded_Professor) (1961)

> The Absent-Minded Professor is a 1961 American comic science fiction
> family film distributed by Walt Disney Productions based on the short
> story "A Situation of Gravity" by Samuel W. Taylor. The title
> character was based in part on Hubert Alyea, a professor emeritus of
> chemistry at Princeton University, who was known as "Dr. Boom" for his
> explosive demonstrations. The film stars Fred MacMurray as Professor
> Ned Brainard.
>
> ...
>
> For a more successful demonstration, **he makes his Model T fly by bombarding Flubber with radioactive particles**.
>
> ...
>
> The Professor retrieves the old Model T from the warehouse, and Hawk is arrested for having a gun in his possession, when the car crashes into a police car. **Eventually, Brainard shows his discovery to the government, after being scared by a missile in flight,** and also wins back Miss Carlisle, culminating in a wedding at last.

You can see the professor's trip to Washington in the clip below.

The film enjoyed a sequel, [Son of Flubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Flubber) (1963) and was more recently remade for TV as [The Absent-Minded Professor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094603/) (1988) and the big screen as [Flubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flubber_(film)) (1997) starring the late Robin Williams.

Comment: ^_^ I was a big fan of the movies when I was growing up, mainly the older ones with Fred MacMurray.